# How to find the conditional PDF of Y which is a sum of the source X and noise Z.

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, information-theory

I met a question in my information theory test, in fact I think it is a probability problem. The question is:
Suppose that an analog communication channel with input $X$ and output $Y$ is given by $Y = X + Z$, where $Z$ is a Gaussian noise with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$, that is, its probability density function is given by
$$p_Z\left(z\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
Further suppose that the input $X$ is also a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$, and that $X$ and $Z$ are independent. Answer the following questions.
(1) Find the joint probability density function $p_{XZ}\left(x,z\right)$ of the pair of random variables $\left(X,Z\right)$.
(2) Find the conditional probability density function $p_{Y\vert X}\left(y\vert x\right)$ of Y under the condition that $X = x$.

For the first question, I know because X and Z are independent, so I could just write down the $p_X\left(x\right)$ like $p_Z\left(z\right)$ and then multiply them.
But I got stuck on question 2. Even I know $X = x$, for the ranges of $X$ and $Z$ are all $\left(-\infty,+\infty\right)$ (though probability is low), how will this help me understand $Y$ as I know $X = x$?
If the question asked me to calculate $p_Y\left(y\right)$, of course I know how to do it, for the sum of two normal distribution is also a normal distribution. Also, maybe because I do not know Q2, I cannot image what $P_{Y\vert X}\left(y\vert x\right)$ looks like...
Could you give me some hints on that? Thank you!

Comment: What if you go through the CDF $P[Y\leq y|X=x]=...$. ? Alternatively use the pdf ratio definition of the conditional pdf. Or do both to verify your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Michael, I think from definition your answer is right, but as I try to write the CDF as you hinted me, I am still not so clear about the effect of $X=x$ and do not know where this condition could be used for the $P(Y<y)$. For as I know the probability is always $0$ if we take one value from a continuous distribution, right?...

Comment: Why are you telling us that log stands for natural logarithm?

Comment: Ah, this may be because I did not offer the full version of the question... In fact, in question 3 and 4, it asks to calculate the mutual entropy of $X,Y$, but as Q1 and Q2 is solved they are easy. I will delete this sentence, sorry for inconvenience...

Comment: I thought you would substitute the definition of $Y$ as the next step in my ... hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$[Y\mid X=x]\stackrel{d}{=}[X+Z\mid X=x]\stackrel{d}{=}[x+Z\mid X=x]\stackrel{d}{=}x+Z$$

where the last statement is based on independence of $X$ and $Y$.

I used $\stackrel{d}{=}$ here because actually we are dealing with equality of *distributions* while "$Y$ under condition $X=x$" cannot be recognized as a random variable.

It is stated here that under condition $X=x$ the distribution of $Y$ coincides with the distribution of $x+Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering @drhab, do you mean that now $(Y|X=x)$ follows a.... mean $x$, variance $\sigma^2+1$ 's normal distribution?

Comment: No, but $[Y\mid X=x]\sim\text{Normal}(x,\sigma^2)$ because $x+Z\sim\text{Normal}(x,\sigma^2)$. Here $x$ is a constant.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed it is. I am sorry for my stupid but could you teach me what $P_{Y\vert X}\left(y\vert x\right)$ looks like? Like we can multiply the $p_X\left(x\right)$ again to $P(Y|X=x)$?

Comment: $p_{Y\mid X=x}(y)=p_{x+Z}(y)=p_{Z}(y-x)$ and $p_Z$ is known. Here $p_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$ is (I think) another notation for $p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$.